# Western Digital Caviar Green hard drive not mounting in Windows 7

Tags: hard-drive, mount

My Western Digital Caviar Green 2TB hard drive will not mount in Windows 7 for some reason.

I loaded it into a SATA enclosure to see if I could partition it in Windows XP, and it says it's a healthy GPT protected partition. It won't mount on my Windows 7 computer though, so what can I do to get it working?

Comment: what partition type? - i'm guessing if its GPT, it might be from a mac, and as such HFS+

Comment: what versions are you OSs ?(32 or 64 ?)

Comment: I have windows 7 32 bit. The HD I bought new from newegg. I tried formatting it into ntfs but it wouldn't mount after that. And now, when its viewed in disk management in xp it says GPT protected. >_<

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to tell for certain, but enough to get started

XP detects the drive as a GPT protected partition, so that it won't accidentally do nasty [MBR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463525) related things to it since the drive appears to be GPT based.

We don't know the filetype - the 'easiest' way would be to try to mount it on a linux livecd and check, maybe using [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) - the simplest way would be to use df -t in a terminal or You could use gparted for a graphical interface. If its NTFS, and its some random glitch, sometimes you can recover the data from linux and reformat.

Assuming we need to check in windows, and its an unsupported filetype, a good bet is HFS+ since OS X uses GPT by default (plausible, since most hard drives are still MBR formatted) you could check with [HFS Explorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsx.html) if its that, and what's there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It isn't a mac formatted hd. I bought it new from newegg and tried to format it in windows 7 after connecting it to my motherboard. I am thinking there was some sort of glitch because after I tried to format it with the guid option, it mounted but transferred data incredibly slow. When I restarted, it was not visible.